# ParamConverter based on HTTP header value

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am creating a Jersey application using Jersey version 2.27.

One of my resources is using @QueryParam to read a query parameter value.

I am creating a ParamConverter and ParamConverterProvider such that I can specify the type of the parameter:

```
@GET
public MyObject getObject(@QueryParam("myvalue") MyParamObject param) {

}
```

My issue is that the parsing of the query parameter depends on the value of an HTTP header.

How do I access the HTTP headers of the request inside a ParamConverter?

I have tried injecting the ContainerRequestContext inside the ParamConverterProvider, but this results in the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by injecting a `ServiceLocator` inside the `ParamConverterProvider` and pass it to the `ParamConverter`. The `ParamConverter` can then fetch the `ContainerRequestContext` in the `fromString()` method:

```
public Message fromString(final String value) {
    final ContainerRequestContext requestContext = injector.getService(ContainerRequestContext.class);
}
```

Comment: You can also inject it as `javax.inject.Provider<ContainerRequestContext>`. If you only need headers you can also just inject `HttpHeaders`.